# how to write login code to application once instead of writing login in every testclass,in TestNG and selenium webdriver ? given below more details

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, testng

**This is base class where i am opening browser and extending it to testclasses**

```java
public class Base_Class{

    public WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browsername")
    public void Start_Browser(String browsername) throws IOException {
        if (browsername.equals("chrome")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//drivers//chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();

        }

        if (browsername.equals("edge")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//drivers//edgedriver.exe");
            driver = new EdgeDriver();
        }

        driver.get(Utilities_Class.read_Prop_Filedata("url"));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    // @Aftertest
    public void Close_Browser() {
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

---

**this is first testclass where i am performing login**

```java
public class LoginTest extends Base_Class {
    
LoginPage lp;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        lp = new LoginPage(driver);
    
    }

    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void Login_test() throws IOException {
        lp.inp_LoginPage_Uname(Utilities_Class.read_Prop_Filedata("username"));
        lp.inp_LoginPage_Pass(Utilities_Class.read_Prop_Filedata("password"));
        lp.click_LoginPage_lgnbtn();
        String title = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        Assert.assertEquals(title, "https://www.saucedemo.com/inventory.html");
    }

    
}
```

---

**this is second testclass where i have mentioned post login activity**

```java
public class AddToCartTest extends Base_Class
{


    inventoryPage ip;
    cartPage cp;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup()
    {
        ip = new inventoryPage(driver);
        cp = new cartPage(driver);

    }
    
    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void Addtocarttest() throws InterruptedException {
        ip.click_inventorypage_addtocartbtn();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        ip.click_inventorypage_carticon();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String acttext = cp.get_cartpage_firsteletext();
        String exptext = "Sauce Labs Backpack";
        Assert.assertEquals(acttext, exptext);
    }


}
```

**now when i tryint to run both test classes in testng.xml file first testclass is getting passed but second testclass is getting failed. where i am making mistake please help me...thankyou**

```
     <suite name="Suite">
    
    <listeners>
            <listener class-name="com.sa.libraryfiles.ExtentReportManager" />
        </listeners>
        <parameter name="browsername" value="chrome"/>
      <test  name="Test">
        <classes>
          <class name="com.sa.testclass.LoginTest"/>
          <class name="com.sa.testclass.AddToCartTest"/>
        </classes>
      </test>
    </suite>
```

[console output after running testng.xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YelrV.png)

Comment: What's the failure output?

Comment: hi, i am getting null pointer exception

Comment: i have attached console image at bottom

Comment: Dunno what's the line 30 in class `AddToCartTest`, but something is null. Put breakpoint direct before line 30 and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

1- Try to do the setup with @BeforeSuite instead @BeforeTest. Usually this is a better practice. I use @BeforeSuite to set class variables such as browsername, environment etc and then I do the driver call always at a @BeforeClass level.

2- Also am not sure from the code how you ever get to the inventory page. Is that the page you get after you login?